# How to Split a string by numbers

Tags: batch-file

how can i do that string split to varibale in a win bat script?

AA.BB.CC.S01E01.CC.DD.AA.DD from start to and with S01E01

i need: AA.BB.CC.S01E01

```
set str=AA.BB.CC.S01E01.CC.DD.AA.DD
set str=%str:.*S[0-9]*E[0-9]*.=&rem;%
echo %str%
```

output is with this code is same from input.

AA.BB.CC.S01E01.CC.DD.AA.DD

Comment: sorry, no REGEX in batch (with the exception of `findstr`, which does a quite crippled subset of REGEX)

Comment: do you have an idea with findstr?

Comment: __FINDSTR__ always outputs the entire line and never just the string matched by expression inside a line. Is `S01E01` always the fourth dot delimited substring and there is always just one `.` used between the elements? Yes, then you can use for example `for /F tokens^=1-4^ delims^=.^ eol^= %%I in ("%str%") do set "str=%%I.%%J.%%K.%%L"`.

Comment: Is batch a mandatory? Probably it would be better to consider Powershell or VBScript instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are in a position to know that the initial string value matches the expected format.

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%A in ("%str%") do set "str=%%A.%%B.%%C.%%D"
```